# Split Values on AlphaNumeric Change into Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following output from a Stored Procedure and I'm trying to split out *Valueasstring* where it switches between numeric and alpha into it's own row and have a couple values updated:

```
Acct    Valuetypename   Valueasstring   EffectiveDate
123     Accepted        150ABC          8/15/2017
234     Accepted        500DF           10/17/2017
345     Accepted        1000ABC         10/17/2017
456     Accepted        25PV            10/3/2017
567     Accepted        100PV           8/15/2017
```

I've tried to split out by a set character, like a comma using XML but am stuck on how to do it on a type change.  I'm not set on using XML.

```sql
Select a.Acct, a.Valuetypename, b.Valueasstring as ValueAsString, a.EffectiveDate
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    CAST('<X>'+replace(T.Valueasstring,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as my_Xml 
    FROM MyTable T
) a
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as Valueasstring
    FROM a.my_Xml.nodes('X') as my_Data(D)
) b
```

What I'm trying to achieve, multiple rows, `valuetypename` changed to alpha value and *Valueasstring* changed to 1 (yes).

```
Acct    Valuetypename   Valueasstring   EffectiveDate
123     ABC             1               8/15/2017
123     Accepted        150             8/15/2017
234     DF              1               10/17/2017
234     Accepted        500             10/17/2017
345     ABC             1               10/17/2017
345     Accepted        1000            10/17/2017
456     PV              1               10/3/2017
456     Accepted        25              10/3/2017
567     PV              1               8/15/2017
567     Accepted        100             8/15/2017
```

I'm only able to find how to delimit on a set character, in my code a comma.  But in my case I do not have a set character, there isn't even a space, just a switch from Alpha to Numeric and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could separated them by comma `,`.. `(i.e. 150, ABC`) by using `stuff()` function.

```
select 
       a.Acct,
       case when ISNUMERIC(m.value('.', 'varchar(max)')) <> 1 then m.value('.', 'varchar(max)') else a.Valuetypename end [Valuetypename],
       case when ISNUMERIC(m.value('.', 'varchar(max)')) <> 1 then '1' else m.value('.', 'varchar(max)') end [Valueasstring],
       a.EffectiveDate from
(
    SELECT *, CAST('<m>'+replace(STUFF(Valueasstring,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', Valueasstring),0,','),',','</m><m>')+'</m>' as XML) as my_Xml  FROM  MyTable 
)a cross apply my_Xml .nodes('/m') as Valueasstring(m)
```

And, check the numeric values by `isnumeric()` function with help of simple `case` expression

Result :

```
Acct    Valuetypename   Valueasstring   EffectiveDate
123     ABC             1               8/15/2017
123     Accepted        150             8/15/2017
234     DF              1               10/17/2017
234     Accepted        500             10/17/2017
345     ABC             1               10/17/2017
345     Accepted        1000            10/17/2017
456     PV              1               10/3/2017
456     Accepted        25              10/3/2017
567     PV              1               8/15/2017
567     Accepted        100             8/15/2017
```

Comment: This is great and exactly what I needed, thank you!  First time using the STUFF function.

Comment: Thank you, first timer and didn't realize the Accept was the check mark.  Done!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a splitting without a delimiting character, but you can use `PATINDEX` to find the first occurance of a pattern:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(Acct INT,Valuetypename VARCHAR(100),Valueasstring VARCHAR(100),EffectiveDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 (123,'Accepted','150ABC','8/15/2017')
,(234,'Accepted','500DF','10/17/2017')
,(345,'Accepted','1000ABC','10/17/2017')
,(456,'Accepted','25PV','10/3/2017')
,(567,'Accepted','100PV','8/15/2017');
```

The query uses `CROSS APPLY` to get the position's value as a *named variable*. It would be possible to place the `PATINDEX` into the query twice, but this is much better to read:

```
SELECT m.Acct
      ,m.Valuetypename
      ,LEFT(Valueasstring,FirstAlpha.Position-1) AS Numpart
      ,SUBSTRING(Valueasstring,FirstAlpha.Position,4000) AS Restpart
      ,m.EffectiveDate
FROM @mockupTable AS m
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',m.Valueasstring) AS Position) AS FirstAlpha
```

The result

```
Acct              Numpart   Restpart    EffectiveDate
123     Accepted    150     ABC         2017-08-15
234     Accepted    500     DF          2017-10-17
345     Accepted    1000    ABC         2017-10-17
456     Accepted    25      PV          2017-10-03
567     Accepted    100     PV          2017-08-15
```

You can use a simple `CAST (... AS INT)` to cast the Numpart to a number.